# What is the proper way to add a png file to an Xcode folder?

Tags: iphone

Have been adding files to Xcode for quite some time, and have been organizing them in "Groups". Everything seems to be working as expected.  But recently I have added a folder to test an html file with 2 png images.  The html file can reference the second png image but the first png image just refuses to be recognized.

I think there must be something that I have missed about Xcode folders.

Hope somebody knowledgable could help...

```
<center><img src="first_button.png" ></center>    


<left><H4>The button is located at the bottom of the screen.         
</H4>


<BR>

<center><H3>

    Another button description

</H3>
</center>


<center><img src="A_icon_11_red.png" width="45" height="45"></center>

<BR>
```

The above runs perfectly ok if fed into Safari.  But UIWebView would miss the first png image.  Another interesting point is that when I change both png file names to be A_icon_11_red.png, everything would come out as expected.  So I think it has to do with the way first_button.png is added to the project.

About the bundle directory, I have the following ...

```
if ((f_path = [bundle pathForResource : @"about_screen" 
                               ofType : @"html" 
                          inDirectory : @"about_html"]) != nil)

{         

// additional lines ...    

}
```

Comment: It's probably as simple as a misspelling. Post the html and perhaps your file system structure pls

Comment: In your HTML file, if ran form the device / simulator, you need to point to the NSBundle, not the full path of the image, or even just "image.png" unless the html and png are copied to your app bundle in the mainBundle and not as a **folder reference**.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The relevant html code is posted as requested.

Comment: @WrightsCS, have added the relevant code about the NSBundle pointer.  I think it should be ok since the "inDirectory" parameter already specified the base URL...

Comment: Was the "about_html" directory added as a folder reference and not just copied? You can verify this by the about_html folder should be blue *(instead of the yellowish color)* in your project browser. Also, explore the app bundle *(from the Simulator directory)* and verify that the folder exists and not just the contents of the folder.

Comment: Thanks @WrightsCS, I will do as suggested now ...  Also the folder is light blue, not yellow.

Comment: Okay, then it is a folder reference. Are the .png images inside this folder?

Comment: All the .png files are under the light blue folder icon in Xcode.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15874/discussion-between-stanley-and-wrightscs)